# python discord music bot youtube_dl

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord

import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands
-----------------------------------------------
@cat.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send('you are not connected to a voice channel')
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice.client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop = client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player)
        
    await ctx.send(f'**Music:**{player.title}')
```

Is there any way to fix this error?

```
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this working example.

```
import discord

import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}   

def endSong(guild, path):
    os.remove(path)                                   

@cat.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send('you are not connected to a voice channel')
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    guild = ctx.message.guild

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        file = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        path = str(file['title']) + "-" + str(file['id'] + ".mp3")

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda x: endSong(guild, path))
    voice_client.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice_client.source, 1)

    await ctx.send(f'**Music: **{url}')
```

### Optional, useful function

If you want you can make your bot leave the voice channel after the song stops playing. Add this at the end of your code:

```
while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    else:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        print("Disconnected")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `if not ctx.message.author.voice:` with `if 'voice' not in ctx.message.author:`

Comment: error:
voice_channel = server.voice.client

AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice'

Comment: @return2749 perform a similar check on `voice_channel = server.voice.client` to see if it has a `voice` key: `if 'voice' not in server:`...